# How to extract data from a NSArray fill with NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

i try to make a kind of "sql distinct" request with core data,
  so i set up my NSFetchrequest like this

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"my_table" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first_property",@"second_property",nil]];

// Execute the fetch
NSError *error;
table_dom = [[NSArray alloc] init];
table_dom = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];
```

this looks ok for me but I think I retrieve an NSArray fill with NSDictionary, is  that rigth ?

So my question is how can I extract data from table_dom for a tableview, I try many things but no ones work ?

It has to be:
    cell.textLabel.text =  //"first property" and 
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = //"second_property"

Or perhaps to make it simple, can I retrieve objects with setReturnsDistinctResults instead of NSDictionary ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you will get a `NSArray` filled with `NSDictionary`. First I would like to point out you have a memory leak in your code. `table_dom = [[NSArray alloc] init];` is not necessary since `executeFetchRequest:error:` will return an `NSArray`. So just remove that line.

After you have your array you can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [table_dom objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"first_property"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"second_property"];
```

Comment: thanks it works great, but I also add "self.table_dom" to make it works 100% because it used to crashed when i was scrolling the tableview (In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method)

Comment: yes, that is probably the easiest way. Otherwise you can do a [table_dom retain] as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why not you can access in forms of objects so for this 
remove

```
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

and

```
 [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first_property",@"second_property",nil]];
```

then Now

```
table_dom = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

table_dom having objects of your entity so where you use this array
extract objects and access both property first_property and second_property
by simply using . operator.

Comment: I cant remove the setPropertiesToFetch method because it works in addition of setReturnsDistinctResults. Check out apple doc -> If YES, the request returns only distinct values for the fields specified by propertiesToFetch.